Jetpack Compose: A clickable TextField with Ripple effect
I'm trying to create a clickable TextField in compose, no matter OutlinedTextField or BasicTextField. I just need the look of the material TextField with the label and borders. What I'm using currently is:
 BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(
        interactionSource =  MutableInteractionSource(),
        indication = LocalIndication.current,
        onClick = { ..do something },
    ), ...

But unfortunately, the ripple effect doesn't have rounded borders:

Is it possible to implement a clickable TextField with the right ripple effect?
